# Adding data from Mongo to GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, rest, mongodb

I'm finishing my last degree on informatics but I'm having trouble getting Tiles/Layers.
I have a DB on MongoDB - with this Schema (GeoJSON)

db.stations.insert({
    "name": "station 1",
     "geometry": { 
"coordinates": [
            50,60
       ],
         "type": "Point"
     }
 })

I'm trying to integrate with Geoserver to get WMS. I got the Mongo Plugin and I can use it to add a New Store.
After the Store. It shows empty. What should I do next? Or what am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mongodb/index.html ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then please [edit] your question to include details of what you have tried, and where you are having trouble.

Comment: I get this error : getLayers error; tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>
getLayers error; Could not initialize class com.mongodb.Mongo How to fix this? I have installed the files from javascript folder of gt-mongodb

Comment: Keep getting the same problem. No errors are found (in cmd's) but nothing shows up after adding the MongoDB on Geoserver. Created the 2dsphere and so. Someone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can (as [Daniel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/27546/daniel-demonceau) suggests) add the [MongoDB extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mongodb/index.html) to GeoServer which will allow you to view the data as a WMS or WMTS (tiles) in your OpenLayers app. You could also look at using the WFS-T standard to handle the updates via GeoServer and could then make use of any of the [supported datastores](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/index.html) to store your data.

Comment: Should the data on MongoDB be as GeoJSON?
 {
  "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ 45.52, -122.681944 ]
    }
}
I tried it but it as normal BSON but it returned nothing (asked for new Features & so)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create an index on your collection:

```
db.stations.createIndex({ geometry: "2dsphere" });
```

After this command I was able to find the collection in the layer list